# Auto-login to Alfresco via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm new to using Alfresco Community 5.0.d, and I'm attempting to allow a specific user to log in without going through the login page form. Specifically, I need to set up a button that, when it is clicked, the underlying JavaScript gets the session of a knowledge user and logs into Alfresco.

Are there any APIs that allow me to get a session ID (or something like that) to create a cookie and allow the user to be logged into Alfresco? If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Should the user access only Alfresco or both Share and Alfresco?

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but I'd try working with tickets if you want to authenticate without the form.

[ALFRESCO_URL]/alfresco/service/api/login?u=&pw=

This will give you a string which you can pass as a parameter to many Alfresco services. The parameter is alf_ticket.

This page talks about obtaining the ticket:

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/RESTful-RepositoryLoginticketGet.html

Answer (score 0):

Does the user need access only to Alfresco or both Share and Alfresco?

What type of access does the user need ? If the user needs only to invoke Alfresco webscripts, the solution suggested by "matthew p." is the best.

If the user needs to access also Share a better solution can be the external authentication http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/auth-external-intro.html

In some cases it could be necessary to implement a custom authentication. It is not difficult, but it is not so straightforward either.

To respond to your question, no there isn't a way to create a session as you were thinking. The external authentication expects that you somehow provides the authenticated user as in the http header of your request. For example, if you login the user on the front end (the apache http server for example or IIS), you can automatically add this header to any request sent to Alfresco.